# Propel, Having fields with spaces

Tags: sql-server-2005, propel

Is it possible to have a space in the field name that is defined in the schema.xml?

*The bright spark who design* the database, used field names like 'POST CODE' and 'CURRENT'

Is there a way around this? or am i stuck?

> The database is an existing MSSQL 2005 database, with an *unknown*
>   number of systems connected to it. So it cannot be changed.
>
> I am using the reverse command to generate the schema.xml
>
> ```
> propel-gen . reverse
> ```

Propel 1.6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around i have found is to remove the space in schema.xml, and then manually change each of the Base*Peer files.

e.g. Change

```
const POSTCODE = 'Customer.POSTCODE';
const POSTCODE = 'Customer.CURRENT';
```

to

```
const POSTCODE = 'Customer.[POST CODE]';
const POSTCODE = 'Customer.[CURRENT]';
```

### Update:

I relised that i just need to add the 2 lines to the `CustomerPeer.php` not `BaseCustomerPeer.php`, that way i dont need to remeber it next time propel is built.